# How to get the string out of a box which a user has inputted into? Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello i am making a log in program on tkinter and i am having trouble when using the box widget where the user is able to input a string. i am trying to take that string out and store it in a variable ready for another time but the way i am trying to do it doesn't actually save anything, is there something that im doing wrong?

```
 from tkinter import *
 Wsignup = Tk()
 Wsignup.title('Sign up')

 UserLabel = Label(Wsignup, text = "Please enter your new username: ")
 UserLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = E)
 UserEntry = Entry(Wsignup)
 UserEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = E)
 Username = UserEntry.get()

 PassLabel = Label(Wsignup, text = "Please enter your new password: ")
 PassLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = E)
 PassEntry = Entry(Wsignup, show = '*')
 PassEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)
 Password = PassEntry.get()
```

Comment: You are calling `get()` before the user had a chance to enter something. Add a Button and call `get()` in a callback function instead.

Comment: Also you will need a call to `mainloop` to make the GUI work. Something like `Wsignup.mainloop()` at the end. Otherwise the GUI closes directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `get()` before the user had a chance to enter something. Add a Button and call `get()` in a callback function instead:

```
def callback():
    # global Username, Password # if you want to set global variables
    Username = UserEntry.get()
    Password = PassEntry.get()
    print(Username, Password) # or whatever you need to do with them

Button(Wsignup, text="Login", command=callback).grid(row=3,column=1)
```